# Google App Engine Memcache API Quotas

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, quota, gae-quotas

Google App Engine's [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits) states that memcache calls will count towards a quota. Yet, when I click through, memcache quotas or cost is not listed. How can I find the new pricing changes?

Comment: Did you figure out how the pricing works for Memcache operations?  I've been looking for a while and haven't found anything.

Comment: No, I was under the impression that because Memcache is unpredictable, there's no pricing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it in your app [dashboard](https://appengine.google.com/dashboard) :

> dashboard -> main -> Quota Details -> Memcache

Comment: Yep, it's there allright. Though in that view you only see the consumption for (up to) the last 24 hours, you don't really have a history of it.

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu ya, you might create a history log by yourself if you can. ;) BTW, I find there're several charts in dashboard, I think the GAE just stats the history only for those.

Comment: yeah but if you do that you're increasing your resource usage, especialy if you want to have a detailed output like the console has for other stats. You might get away with it if you put it in an async task, but then you're not doing a real time logging of it.